# Scrollspy active not working with bootsrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, scrollspy

I need a help. I used the code from Bootstrap example but it didn't work.

I put data target on Javascript, and i also put data-target on body.
The code is full copy from bootstrap-5 scrollspy, but i don't completely understand how to use it. Thank you for your help.

```js
 $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar-example2' });
```

```html
<body data-target="#navbar-example2">
<nav id="navbar-example2" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light px-3 fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading1">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading2">About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading3">Skills</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading4">My Project</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar-example2" data-bs-offset="0" class="scrollspy-example" tabindex="0">
      <section id="scrollspyHeading1">
      </section>
      <section id="scrollspyHeading2">
      </section>
      <section id="scrollspyHeading3">
      </section>
      <section id="scrollspyHeading4">
      </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery with Bootstrap 5?

Comment: no, i just put JS for data-target

Comment: Oh, confused as to why `$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar-example2' });` is in the question at all

Comment: I found that code while searching for how to fix scrollspy. Actually, that has the same function as data-target on body html.

Comment: Do you understand this it's jQuery code? Bootstrap 5 no longer requires jQuery. That's why I asked if you were using jQuery,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/scrollspy/#how-it-works)..

> "Scrollable containers and keyboard access If you’re making a
> scrollable container (other than the ), be sure to have a height
> set and overflow-y: scroll;..."

For example,

```
.scrollspy-example {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/RZcss5v7OW)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get the point. Is that mean to put overflow-y: scroll; on css body?

Comment: thank you so much, it's help. bc of your help, i'm trying to figure other, and it's finally the things i've been looking. I put the data-bs-spy="scroll" in body instead of create a div.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing **`data-bs-spy="scroll"`** into **`data-spy="scroll"`**.

Here is a link to an example from the bootstrap documentation that shows the use of `data-spy="scroll"`
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/#example-in-navbar